# PowerShell module works but NOT in AWS PowerShell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cli

I am currently trying to use the [PSlogging](http://9to5it.com/powershell-logging-v2-easily-create-log-files/) module within AWS PowerShell for creating logs. Now the module works fine in the standard PowerShell but in AWS PowerShell I am getting errors, I even did a Get-Module so I know AWS is finding the module... so if anyone knows why it won't work, that would be great!!

[image]

Here is a photo showing the module appearing under ISE PowerShell but not AWS PowerShell within the default windows PowerShell folder.

[image]

Comment: Why is PSLogging module under `C:\program files (x86)\AWS Tools\Powershell`? [The install guide](http://9to5it.com/powershell-logging-v2-easily-create-log-files/) has it under `$Home\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` or `$Env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`.

Comment: I tried putting the module under C:\program files (x86)\AWS Tools\Powershell after discovering it wouldn't work under C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules I have attached a photo showing it appears under PS ISE but not PS AWS